# I am trying to indent data when displaying using \t in swift but it isn't working

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode7

I am trying to print() out the two arrays but instead of displaying in a row with a \t(tab) in between each number.
 it is displaying in a column and no \t. 
Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
for j in 0 ..< dicePossibleNum.count
{
    print("\(dicePossibleNum[j])\t") //displays possible dice numbers
}


print("\n==================================================\n")

for i in 0 ..< diceResult.count
{
    print("\(diceResult[i])\t") // displays dice results
}
```

Here is the result

2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12

==================================================

4
2
7
4
21
18
14
13
6
10
2

Thank you for any help,
I'm all new to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift 'print()' function appends a newline by default. Try

`print("Hello", terminator:"")`

This makes 'print()' add an empty string at the end of the line, instead of a newline. You could also try:

```
print("Hello", terminator:"\t")
```

...which would add a tab at the end of the line.

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple way try this code..

```
 let dicePossibleNum : NSArray = ["1","2", "3","4","5","6", "7","8","9","10", "11","12",]
 let totalcount : Int = dicePossibleNum.count as Int

 for j in 0..<totalcount {
      print("Hello", dicePossibleNum[j],"\t")
 }
```

Output :

```
Hello 1     
Hello 2     
Hello 3     
Hello 4     
Hello 5     
Hello 6     
Hello 7     
Hello 8     
Hello 9     
Hello 10    
Hello 11    
Hello 12
```